# How to select multiple web elements with the same x path using web driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, bots

I am building a java bot using selenium in order to automate a process and I ran into some trouble. There is 5 drop down menus in which I need to select "select all" however the "select all" button has the same xpath and classname for each drop down so the system is not recognizing that. Ive attached a picture so you can see the drop downs. Please if you know how I can select these elements that would be great.

[image: Image of drop downs]

The xpath for the select all exists as `= "//*[@id=\"capability-filter\"]/div[2]/div[1]"`

Comment: Your XPath is selecting a div. Not a select option or a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using indexing here if they all have same xpath then use:

```
(//*[@id="capability-filter"]/div[2]/div1)[1]
```

this will select the first element from this list.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there are 5 dropdown menu so in the for-loop specified size is 5

```
  for(int i = 1 ; i<=5 ; i++){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath((("//*[@id=\'capability-filter']/div[2]/div)["+i+"]")))).click();
  }
  Hope above code will help you
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the only problem with this code is that "/div[2]/div["+i+"] will not work because the for loop will change the value of i from 1->2->3 .. etc. meanwhile the xpath for the element does not increment i. The ex path div index remains as a constant value of 1 for all 5 drop downs. Therefore the for loop was not successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"capability-filter\"]/div[2]/div[1]"));


for(WebElement e: ele){


String drop = e.getText.toString();
if(drop.equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")){
    e.click();
    break;  
}
```